# Why $locationProvider.html5Mode causes Infinite $digest Loop?

Tags: angularjs

If I set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, my application return: `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! (...)`. My code snippets are below.

My routes config:

```
function configRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, routeConfigProvider) {
  var routes = routeConfigProvider.$get();

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/default');

  $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/route1');
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/route1', '/route1/route11');
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/route2', '/route2/route22');

  // Register all routes.
  for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
    var route = routes[i];
    $stateProvider
      .state(route.state, route.options);
  }
}
```

My web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do not use

> $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/default');

replace with:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
     var $state = $injector.get("$state");
     $state.go("default.state");
 });
```

replace "default.state" with your default state

Comment: Was not working before for other reasons, made other changes and now worked. Thank u.

Comment: It works perfect! but why I should not use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/default');`?

Comment: @Jobsamuel Looks like this is a bug with ui-router when you use the combination of $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/default") with the $stateChangeStart.

Issue reported here : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/600